# Child Account does not show at Login Screen

Tags: windows, windows-10, microsoft-family-safety

After Setting up a new computer, I am trying to setup Child Account on the same PC. Everything looks okay in my opinion, but I do not see his account on the Login Screen. Any pointers?

[image: Account Settings]

[image: Child Account Listed]

[image: No option to switch user]

Comment: Did you do all the steps described in [this article](https://www.howtogeek.com/225323/how-to-add-and-monitor-a-childs-account-in-windows-10/), and especially clicked "Accept Invitation" in the email invitation sent during the account creation process.

Comment: Here is an article talking about [How to set up a kid-friendly Windows 10 device with a child account](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-set-kid-friendly-windows-10-pc-child-account), you could have a look.